# SQL query to get single row value from an aggregate

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have an Oracle table with two columns ID and START_DATE, I want to run a query to get the ID of the record with the most recent date, initially i wrote this:

```
 select id from (select * from mytable order by start_date desc) where rownum = 1
```

Is there a more cleaner and efficient way of doing this? I often run into this pattern in SQL and end up creating a nested query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM mytable)
```

Still a nested query, but more straightforward and also, in my experience, more standard.

Comment: Better, but I think OP wanted to avoid nested queries. I would have tried something with analytic functions... but not sure that would work... hmm...

Comment: This fulfils the 'get all records with the most recent start date', which the OPs query doesn't.  +1

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really trying to avoid nested queries, I'm very new to SQL so I just wanted to know if what i'm doing is common (or bad) sql coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a pretty clean and efficient solution to me - I don't think you can get any better than that, of course assuming that you've an index on start_date.  If you want all ids for the latest start date then froadie's solution is better.